# Python: List index is out of range

Tags: python

I am making some 'password-cracking' software for fun with python. (Not for actual password cracking, for a randomly generated password) However when I run it, it says this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Password Cracker.py", line 14, in <module>
    if chars[trys] == example[index]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't know what the error is here, because this happens as soon as I run the code, and by default, index is set to 0, so how can it be out of range?

Here is my code:

```
import random
import string

chars = list(string.ascii_lowercase) + list(string.ascii_lowercase.upper())
print(chars)
trys = 0
rounds = 8
index = 0

example = (random.choice(chars) + random.choice(chars) + random.choice(chars) + random.choice(chars) + random.choice(chars) + random.choice(chars) + random.choice(chars) + random.choice(chars))
password = ""

while rounds != 0:
    if chars[trys] == example[index]:
        password = chars[trys]
        rounds -= 1
        index +=1
    else:
        trys += 1

print(password)
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: You're incrementing `trys` and `index` in your loop, so at some point one of these two numbers is having a greater value than the length of `password`

Comment: BTW, `string.ascii_lowercase.upper()` is a strange way to write `string.ascii_uppercase`.

Answer (score 1):

Increment index and decrements rounds should not be inside `if` block. This should be irrespective on `if` or `else` case.

You can try:

```
while rounds != 0:
    if chars[trys] == example[index]:
        password = chars[trys]

    else:
        trys += 1

    rounds -= 1
    index +=1

print(password)
```